# Trying to integrate google assistant to python via ifttt to learn and test some things

Tags: python, python-3.x, webhooks

I'm trying to make a listener, to see what I'm posting via ifttt, but I'm getting bad request (400) error. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request 
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST']) 
def foo():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    print(request.json)
    return json.dumps(request.json)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.10', port=27015, debug=True)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a client side problem.

The client which posts the data needs to set the following header:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Otherwise `request.json` returns `None` which in your code will trigger the `abort(400)`.

If you can't make the required change on the client, you can use the [get_json()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Response.get_json) method of `request`, and pass `force=True`.  If parsing of the actual payload then fails, it will raise a `BadRequest` exception.

A better way to write this would be:

```
from flask import jsonify, abort

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST']) 
def foo():
    try:
      output =  request.get_json(force=True)
    except:
        abort(400)
    # output is now a dict of the incoming json payload
    print(output)
    return jsonify(output)
```

Then test with a valid payload (but no content type header set):

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/foo -X POST -d '{"one":"two"}'
{
  "one": "two"
}
```

And an invalid payload:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/foo -X POST -d '{"one":"two3}'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
```

Using flask's `jsonify()` function on the outgoing data automatically sets the correct content types on the way out.

---

**Edit**, if you're unsure what data's reaching the endpoint, and can only see a 400 response in the console, then maybe try stripping the function back to basics:

```
@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST']) 
def foo():
    print(request.get_json(force=True))
    return 'works'
```

Some trial / error testing is probably required here.  Attempt to submit via your `ifttt` system as well as the curl commands above.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lk2k.png it is set to application/json;
https://i.imgur.com/DhrB8gw.png that is how it is the server going, with the error

Comment: Have you set the cpanel on screencap #1 to speak `https`?  Looks like your only using the dev server which is `http`.  [similar](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/1029)

Comment: ok, i set it to http. now it outputs that: https://i.imgur.com/kyXLNp4.png

Comment: ops, got it working, finally! just a little thign that i forgot. thanks!

Comment: just one more question, how can i get only the first value ?